# Name and proof of the following theorem from probability theory

Tags: probability-theory

I am looking for a name and proof of the following theorem from probability theory, which I found in a paper whose name I forget.

Let $B(n,p)$ denote the binomial random variable with $n$ trials, each having success probability $p$, i.e. $Pr(B(n,p) = k) = {n \choose k}p^{k}(1-p)^{n-k} $ for all $k \in 0,1,2,..n$.

Let $Y_{1},...,Y_{n}$ be independent Bernoulli trials, each having success probability at most $p$, i.e. $Pr(Y_{i} = 1) \leq p$ for all $i \in 1,2...,n$.

Then $Pr\bigl(\sum^{n}_{i = 1}Y_{i} \geq k\bigr) \leq Pr\bigl(B(n,p) \geq k\bigr) $
for all $k \in 0,1,2,..n$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about a name, but here is a simple way to prove it by set inclusion. Let $U_i$ be iid uniform(0,1) random variables. Define $Y_i=F_i(U_i)$ where $F_i(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & x \in [0,p_i) \\ 0 & x \in [p_i,1] \end{cases}$ and $X_i=F(U_i)$ where $F(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & x \in [0,p) \\ 0 & x \in [p,1] \end{cases}$. Then $\{ \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i \geq k \} \subset \{ \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \geq k \}$ which gets you the result.